# Removing a header name in react table and making it empty

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am trying to create a new checkbox column for a react table. I don't need a header name
for the checkbox column. If I put in an empty string in the header, my app crashes and I get the error message below

```
    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
          {
             //id: 'checkbox',
            Header: '',
            accessor: '',
            width: 25,
            Cell: ({ row }: any) => {
              return <input type='checkbox' className={classes.mystyle} />
            },
          },
          {
            Header: 'Jungle Name',
            accessor: 'JungleMan',
          }
        ]
    )
```

How can I do this with an empty Header?

[image]

Comment: a single space maybe?? ```Header: " "```

Comment: The single space works. Thanks

Comment: how about `Header: true`?

Answer (score 8):

The answers provided in the comments are *technically* correct, but also very much a hack. There is a non-workaround method of doing this: simply provide an `id` key to the Column. This use of `id` is described in the [useTable hook docs](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options):

> Technically speaking, [accessor] isn't required if you have a unique id for a column.

A name like "checkbox" won't fly, because of the requirement to be *unique*. Thus, it should probably be slightly more descriptive.  Furthermore, `Header` is explicitly an Optional property -- you can omit it entirely, to no detriment.

Therefore, your column can just look like:

```js
   const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
          {
            id: 'checkbox-table-column'
            width: 25,
            Cell: ({ row }: any) => {
              return <input type='checkbox' className={classes.mystyle} />
            },
          },
          {
            Header: 'Jungle Name',
            accessor: 'JungleMan',
          }
        ],
      []
    );
```

(Also: fixed the minor typo where the dependency array wasn't passed to `useMemo`. It'll let you do it, but less chances for failure if you pass one, even empty, yourself.)

Answer (score 5):

Add a custom key hideHeader: false, in the columns variable.

[hideHeader: false, in the columns variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDP5R.png)

In the Material table check for this key.

```
<TableHead>
        {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
          <TableRow {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
            {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => {
              return column.hideHeader === false ? null : (
                <TableCell {...column.getHeaderProps()}>
                  {column.render('Header')}
                </TableCell>
              );
            })}
          </TableRow>
        ))}
      </TableHead>
```

[paste to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9n8p.png)

This should remove the empty row from html output.

credit to [link](https://kiranvj.com/blog/blog/react-table-7-x-hide-column-header-row/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `createColumnHelper`, create a `display` column for the checkbox:

```
type Thing = {
    id: number
}

const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<Thing>()


const defaultColumns = [
  columnHelper.display({
    id: 'checkbox-column',
    width: 25,
    cell: () => <input type='checkbox' className={classes.mystyle} />,
  }),
]
```

docs: https://tanstack.com/table/v8/docs/guide/column-defs